# Issue with accessing css border-width property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with css values. Means for example i set the div border-width, like :

```
  $("div").css("border-width", "20px");
```

but when i am accessing the border-width again i got :

```
 var width = $("div").css("border-width");

 width = 19.56740..px ( value something like this )
```

Can anybody please explain me , what i am doing wrong?

Comment: [It works in this simple test.](http://jsfiddle.net/jeGYW/)

Comment: @Pointy but i am getting `Width is 18.88888931274414px` this output from your fiddle

Comment: What browser are you using?  I get 20px in Firefox; I'll try Chrome. (*edit* same in Chrome; it says "Width is 20px")

Comment: Chrome on a "normal" computer?  Hmm ... that's weird.

Comment: yes it is , but now is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Well I have no idea what would cause that. That jsfiddle even works fine on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `border-width` css property doesn't exist. It gets splitted into:

```
border-top-width
border-right-width
border-bottom-width
border-left-width
```

so try to read those, should work like expected.

```
var width = $("div").css("border-top-width");
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-width.asp 
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ ...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I should be more precise. Yes you can *set* the a border width with that value, but once its there, the *computed values* are converted into `border-top-width`, `border-left-width`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

border-width doesn't exist. you have to use the following

border-top-width
border-right-width
border-bottom-width
border-left-width

***JS CODE***

```
$('div').css({'border':'1px solid red', 'border-width':'20px'})
var width = $('div').css('border-top-width');
console.log(width);
```

Comment: border-width property does exist: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-width-properties

Comment: @h4b0 yes but when accessing the properties via jQuery you have to use the individual values (top, right, left, bottom).